# Loop through all rows of ACF group without specifying row name

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

In my advanced custom fields I have a group within a group.

The fields within the inner group are to select parts of meals. Apart from the first row within that group, the format will be exactly the same

[image]

I've written code that outputs the food name and the value associated with each one (multiplied by another variable).

As well as outputting those, the 5th and 6th row have an if statement. They only show if another variable $feeds_per_day is as high as that meal number.

Here is the code...

```
if( have_rows('zero') ):


?><div class="grid-50" style="float: left;"><table><tr><th colspan="2">Zero</th></tr><?php

while( have_rows('zero') ) : the_row(); ?>

        <tr><td>Upon Waking</td><td><?php the_sub_field('upon_waking')?></td></tr>

        <?php 
    if ( have_rows('meal_1') ){ 
        while( have_rows('meal_1') ) {
        the_row();

        $protein_object = (get_sub_field_object('protein_select'));                                 
        $protein_value = get_sub_field('protein_select');                                   
        $protein_label = ($protein_object['choices'][$protein_value]);

        $carb_object = (get_sub_field_object('carb_select'));                                   
        $carb_value = get_sub_field('carb_select');                                 
        $carb_label = ($carb_object['choices'][$carb_value]);

        $fat_object = (get_sub_field_object('fat_select'));                                 
        $fat_value = get_sub_field('fat_select');                                   
        $fat_label = ($fat_object['choices'][$fat_value]);

        $protein_amount = round($zero_protein_feed / $protein_value * 10) *10;
        $fat_amount = round($zero_fat_feed / $fat_value * 10) *10 ;

        ?><tr><td>Meal 1</td><td><?php echo $protein_amount ?>g <?php echo $protein_label ?>, <?php echo $fat_amount ?>g <?php echo $fat_label ?></td></tr><?php }  }

        if ( have_rows('meal_2') ){ 
        while( have_rows('meal_2') ) {
        the_row();

        $protein_object = (get_sub_field_object('protein_select'));                                 
        $protein_value = get_sub_field('protein_select');                                   
        $protein_label = ($protein_object['choices'][$protein_value]);

        $carb_object = (get_sub_field_object('carb_select'));                                   
        $carb_value = get_sub_field('carb_select');                                 
        $carb_label = ($carb_object['choices'][$carb_value]);

        $fat_object = (get_sub_field_object('fat_select'));                                 
        $fat_value = get_sub_field('fat_select');                                   
        $fat_label = ($fat_object['choices'][$fat_value]);

        $protein_amount = round($zero_protein_feed / $protein_value * 10) * 10 ;
        $fat_amount = round($zero_fat_feed / $fat_value * 10) * 10 ;

        ?><tr><td>Meal 2</td><td><?php echo $protein_amount ?>g <?php echo $protein_label ?>, <?php echo $fat_amount ?>g <?php echo $fat_label ?></td></tr><?php } }

        if ( have_rows('meal_3') ){ 
        while( have_rows('meal_3') ) {
        the_row();

        $protein_object = (get_sub_field_object('protein_select'));                                 
        $protein_value = get_sub_field('protein_select');                                   
        $protein_label = ($protein_object['choices'][$protein_value]);

        $carb_object = (get_sub_field_object('carb_select'));                                   
        $carb_value = get_sub_field('carb_select');                                 
        $carb_label = ($carb_object['choices'][$carb_value]);

        $fat_object = (get_sub_field_object('fat_select'));                                 
        $fat_value = get_sub_field('fat_select');                                   
        $fat_label = ($fat_object['choices'][$fat_value]);

        $protein_amount = round($zero_protein_feed / $protein_value * 10) * 10 ;
        $fat_amount = round($zero_fat_feed / $fat_value * 10) * 10 ;

        ?><tr><td>Meal 3</td><td><?php echo $protein_amount ?>g <?php echo $protein_label ?>, <?php echo $fat_amount ?>g <?php echo $fat_label ?></td></tr><?php } }

        if ( have_rows('meal_4') ){ 
        while( have_rows('meal_4') ) {
        the_row();

        $protein_object = (get_sub_field_object('protein_select'));                                 
        $protein_value = get_sub_field('protein_select');                                   
        $protein_label = ($protein_object['choices'][$protein_value]);

        $carb_object = (get_sub_field_object('carb_select'));                                   
        $carb_value = get_sub_field('carb_select');                                 
        $carb_label = ($carb_object['choices'][$carb_value]);

        $fat_object = (get_sub_field_object('fat_select'));                                 
        $fat_value = get_sub_field('fat_select');                                   
        $fat_label = ($fat_object['choices'][$fat_value]);

        $protein_amount = round($zero_protein_feed / $protein_value * 10) * 10 ;
        $fat_amount = round($zero_fat_feed / $fat_value * 10) * 10 ;

        ?><tr><td>Meal 4</td><td><?php echo $protein_amount ?>g <?php echo $protein_label ?>, <?php echo $fat_amount ?>g <?php echo $fat_label ?></td></tr><?php } }

        if ( have_rows('meal_5') ){ 
        while( have_rows('meal_5') ) {
        the_row();

        $protein_object = (get_sub_field_object('protein_select'));                                 
        $protein_value = get_sub_field('protein_select');                                   
        $protein_label = ($protein_object['choices'][$protein_value]);

        $carb_object = (get_sub_field_object('carb_select'));                                   
        $carb_value = get_sub_field('carb_select');                                 
        $carb_label = ($carb_object['choices'][$carb_value]);

        $fat_object = (get_sub_field_object('fat_select'));                                 
        $fat_value = get_sub_field('fat_select');                                   
        $fat_label = ($fat_object['choices'][$fat_value]);

        $protein_amount = round($zero_protein_feed / $protein_value * 10) * 10 ;
        $fat_amount = round($zero_fat_feed / $fat_value * 10) * 10 ;

            if ($feeds_per_day > 4){

        ?><tr><td>Meal 5</td><td><?php echo $protein_amount ?>g <?php echo $protein_label ?>, <?php echo $fat_amount ?>g <?php echo $fat_label ?></td></tr><?php } }

            }

        if ( have_rows('meal_6') ){ 
        while( have_rows('meal_6') ) {
        the_row();

        $protein_object = (get_sub_field_object('protein_select'));                                 
        $protein_value = get_sub_field('protein_select');                                   
        $protein_label = ($protein_object['choices'][$protein_value]);

        $carb_object = (get_sub_field_object('carb_select'));                                   
        $carb_value = get_sub_field('carb_select');                                 
        $carb_label = ($carb_object['choices'][$carb_value]);

        $fat_object = (get_sub_field_object('fat_select'));                                 
        $fat_value = get_sub_field('fat_select');                                   
        $fat_label = ($fat_object['choices'][$fat_value]);

        $protein_amount = round($zero_protein_feed / $protein_value * 10) * 10 ;
        $fat_amount = round($zero_fat_feed / $fat_value * 10) * 10 ;

            if ($feeds_per_day > 5){

        ?><tr><td>Meal 6</td><td><?php echo $protein_amount ?>g <?php echo $protein_label ?>, <?php echo $fat_amount ?>g <?php echo $fat_label ?></td></tr><?php } }

            }


endwhile;

        ?></table></div><?php
        endif;
```

... apart from the first row, I'm repeating a lot of the same code. **Is there a way to cycle through all of the fields and apply the one format if the field is 'upon_waking' and another format if not?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was using a for loop..

```
for ($i=1; $i<$feeds_per_day + 1; $i++) {
   if (have_rows('meal_'.$i)) {
     while (have_rows('meal_'.$i)) {

  the_row();
  //etc...

}}}
```

...alternatively, if my inner rows don't have sequential names I can put them all into an array and loop through them like this...

```
$repeaters = array('zero', 'low', 'medium', 'high');
foreach ($repeaters as $repeater) {
if (have_rows($repeater)) {
while (have_rows($repeater)) {

  the_row();
  // etc...

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this using dynamic values for looping the meal_  : `

```
    $mcount = 0; 
        while( have_rows('zero') ) : the_row(); $mcount++;?>

    <tr><td>Upon Waking</td><td><?php the_sub_field('upon_waking')?></td></tr>

    <?php
    if ( have_rows('meal_'.$mcount) ){ 
    while( have_rows('meal_'.$mcount) ) {
    the_row();

    $protein_object = (get_sub_field_object('protein_select'));                                 
    $protein_value = get_sub_field('protein_select');                                   
    $protein_label = ($protein_object['choices'][$protein_value]);

    $carb_object = (get_sub_field_object('carb_select'));                                   
    $carb_value = get_sub_field('carb_select');                                 
    $carb_label = ($carb_object['choices'][$carb_value]);

    $fat_object = (get_sub_field_object('fat_select'));                                 
    $fat_value = get_sub_field('fat_select');                                   
    $fat_label = ($fat_object['choices'][$fat_value]);

    $protein_amount = round($zero_protein_feed / $protein_value * 10) *10;
    $fat_amount = round($zero_fat_feed / $fat_value * 10) *10 ;

    ?><tr><td>Meal <?php echo$mcount; ?></td><td><?php echo $protein_amount ?>g <?php echo $protein_label ?>, <?php echo $fat_amount ?>g <?php echo $fat_label ?></td></tr><?php }  } ?>`
```

It might work!!

Comment: Ah, it looked good but afraid not! The have_rows function of 'zero' is only firing once. I think its maybe counting itself, zero, as only having one row, rather than counting the sub fields. Thanks though